# Test/Run chrome packaged application in Android Phone

Tags: android, google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I created a chrome packaged app, and already working when I test it on my laptop via **chrome://extensions**.  What I want to do now is to test this on a mobile, specifically in my android phone. I tried transferring my folder in my phone, and run the html, but it doesn't work. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the fact that Chrome on phones isn't the same as the Chrome on desktops.

There is no native support for either extensions or apps in there.

However, a working Chrome App can be *converted* into a native Android/iOS app - but it requires special tools such as Apache Cordova. See the [corresponding docs](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/chrome_apps_on_mobile).

However, also note that [Google's own toolchain](https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/mobile-chrome-apps) for it is abandoned:

> The Chrome Apps for Mobile Toolchain ***is no longer being actively developed***. We intend to keep it functional, but do not intend on adding any new features.